# How can I get information I have created during the button press event to display on my html page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I'm making an asp.net app using visual studio 2010.  I have a text field and button that calls a method on the String in the text field.

```
Enter your address here: <asp:TextBox ID="tb_address" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="GetLatLong" ></asp:Button>
```

In the C# file for the button, I have my GetLatLong method:

```
protected void GetLatLong(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String address = tb_address.Text;
    String query = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=";
    address = address.Replace(" ", "+");
    query += address + "&sensor=false";
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(query);
    String lat = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
    String lon = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
}
```

How can I get my lat and lon Strings to display on my html page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<asp:Label />`s.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLat" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lblLong" runat="server" />

String lat = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
String lon = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
lblLat.Text = lat;
lblLong.Text = lon;
```

Comment: You can save some bits if will perform just a single xpath query (one level upper)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying @abatishchev.

Comment: No problem @GrahamCarling, HTH.

Comment: exec xpath once: `"/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/` then read children. not twice - that's my point

Comment: I understand what you were saying now @abatishchev. I just addressed the question of the OP, how to display strings on the page.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create controls for displaying the results (You can either add them to your form in design mode or add them dynamically on the click event handler). Lets say asp:Labels and then assign the resulting values to those labels.

```
Label result1 = new Label();
result1.Text = lat;
this.Controls.Add(result1);
```

or

have this in your code

```
<asp:Label ID='result1' runat='server' />
```

and then assign the value directly form the code behind.

```
result1.Text = lat;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include some `Literal` controls (or `Label` controls, or any number of other page elements) to hold the values.  The controls would look like this:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LatitudeOutput" />
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LongitudeOutput" />
```

And you'd set their values in the code-behind:

```
String lat = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
String lon = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
LatitudeOutput.Text = lat;
LatitudeOutput.Text = lon;
```

I personally prefer `Literal` controls in many cases because they don't bring any additional mark-up with them.  `Label` controls get wrapped in `span` tags, for example.  But, as with many things, there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a label control on your aspx page. Add this to your aspx page where you want to display the lng and lat

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLat" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lblLng" runat="server" />
```

Then in your code behind

```
lblLat.Text = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
lblLng.Text = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
```

You are setting the Text of the label to the value you get with the SelectSingleNode call.